# Expansion of cmdline-special vs `=

Tags: ex-mode, cmdline

Reading (and re-reading) the Vim docs on when [`:h cmdline-special`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special) expansion happens versus [`` :h `= ``](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%60=) expansion, the `:grep` example below has me stumped:

```
:let &grepprg = "echo 'grep: $*'"          " Adjust 'grepprg' for ease of inspection.
:grep % <cWORD> `="string"`
:!echo 'grep: % <cWORD> `="string"`'       " Note: This produces identical output.
```

Assuming a current file name of `current-file.txt` and that the cursor is on WORD `current-WORD`, the `:grep` command above outputs:

```
grep: current-file.txt current-WORD `="string"`
```

The first two arguments to `:grep` (interpreted by `:h cmdline-special`) were expanded, but the `` `= `` expression was not. Since `:grep` can accept file name arguments, can someone please clarify why only `:h cmdline-special` expansion was performed? My research into the docs is documented below.

---

`:h cmdline-special` states that strings like `%` and `<cWORD>` are expanded "at places where a file name can be used":

> In Ex commands, at places where a file name can be used, the following
> characters have a special meaning. These can also be used in the expression
> function [expand()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29).

This explains why commands which do not expect a file name (e.g. `:normal`) do not perform this expansion:

```
:normal %          " Has same effect as typing "%" in normal mode
```

Now, looking at the docs for `` :h `= ``, the first line states

> You can have the backticks expanded as a Vim expression, instead of as an
> external command, by putting an equal sign right after the first backtick,
> e.g:
>
> ```
>    :e `=tempname()`
> ```

which seems to suggest that `` :h `= `` expansion applies in the same context as [`` :h `-expansion ``](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%60-expansion). `` :h `-expansion `` states:

> On Unix and a few other systems you can also use backticks for the file name
> argument, for example:
>
> ```
>     :next `find . -name ver\\*.c -print`
>     :view `ls -t *.patch  \| head -n1`
> ```

Thus, it seems that all forms of expansion mentioned in this post (`:h cmdline-special`, `` :h `= ``, `` :h `-expansion ``) apply to all `file name` arguments, but the `:grep` example illustrated that it is not so.

Is my interpretation of the docs incorrect or is there more to the notion of "file name argument"? Short of looking at the Vim source code, is there another resource which addresses this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's pretty simple. "Backtick" only works where a file argument stands (like "wildcards", not "cmdline-special"), see `:h backtick-expansion`.

For example, backtick works for `:edit`, `:lcd`, `:argadd`, etc.

Comment: So, youre arguing that vim isn’t sure the non-first argument to `:grep` is a filename? Since OP points out that for other arguments the expansion is valid

Comment: @D.BenKnoble As far as I understand, vim makes a difference between "cmdline-specials" and "wildcards". "Backticks" behave like "wildcards", that is, they are expanded only by (some) internal commands, while being passed onto the shell (`:h :!cmd`) unexpanded.

Comment: It looks like the key is `{file}` in the help; these things only apply to that, if I read correctly

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, you can put it like this: where vim expects file argument, where help says "{file}", and where vim performs "wildcard" expansion. That all must be the same place.